# Mod_rewrite - redirect query string to homepage

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string

Can you help me redirect this url https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/?s=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D to homepage using htaccess? I tried it using rank math redirect but no luck. I have tried this but Im afraid it is wrong.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D
  RewriteRule ^https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Should I do the same thing on htaccess with these URLs? https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/theholisticsanctuary.php?Action=1&k=addiction-rehab-michigan&PageID=288245
https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/?media=1655378697/article/can-artificial-intelligence-provide-a-human-touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan! I will try this out.

Comment: Should I do the same with this URLs? https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/theholisticsanctuary.php?Action=1&k=addiction-rehab-michigan&PageID=288245
https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/?media=1655378697/article/can-artificial-intelligence-provide-a-human-touch

Comment: how about on this URLs https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/theholisticsanctuary.php?Action=1&k=addiction-rehab-michigan&PageID=288245
https://www.theholisticsanctuary.com/?media=1655378697/article/can-artificial-intelligence-provide-a-human-touch. I wanted to redirect in homepage also. I was wondering how to add wildcards. there are so many links that are like that and differes only the numbers.